# How can I draw html5 canvas background properly?

Tags: html, canvas

When I come to close background image end I'am having this problem https://snag.gy/PRwJWD.jpg.

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clear the canvas before you render any of the game content.

```
// ctx is the 2d context and canvas is the canvas element
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

or if you want a set color you can use

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"; // black
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

Both methods will remove the trails you are getting and are done via Hardware so are very fast.